# Increment variable names in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I want to increment variable names in MySQL query. Something like this:

```
 DELIMITER $$
 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test$$
 CREATE PROCEDURE test()
 BEGIN
 DECLARE y  INT;
 SET y = 0;
 WHILE y  <= 7 DO

 // insert query

// i want to increment a variable name like
// concat(@variable_name,"_",y) = last_insert_id();

// ....

SET  y = y + 1; 
END WHILE;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of variables, you can use an array-like temporary table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table (id INT, value INT);

INSERT INTO temp_table (id)
VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7);
```

Your procedure would look like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
BEGIN
  DECLARE y INT;
  SET y = 0;
  WHILE y  <= 7 DO

    // insert query

    UPDATE temp_table
    SET value = last_insert_id()
    WHERE id = y;

    SET  y = y + 1;

  END WHILE;
END$$
```

The values can be afterwards retrieved using SELECT query:

```
DECLARE myvar INT;

SELECT value
INTO myvar
FROM temp_table
WHERE id = 1; <- "index" of your desired value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PREPARE and EXECUTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) to do this. I'm showing it in the mysql client environment below, but you can do the same thing in a stored procedure.

```
mysql> set @sql = CONCAT('SET @foo, 1, ' = 123');

mysql> prepare stmt from @sql;
Statement prepared

mysql> execute stmt;

mysql> select @foo1;
+-------+
| @foo1 |
+-------+
|   123 |
+-------+
```

However, I worry that you're asking an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You should consider if there's another way you can write your code that doesn't require an indefinite number of variables. For example, after your insert, do whatever you were going to do with the resulting insert id.

Consider using application code to do the insert instead of a stored procedure. I avoid using MySQL stored procedures.